# tcp get client's ip from edittext

Tags: java, tcp

I have tcp multithreaded server ,which i will run on android device and client on pc, server only receives messages and sends msg back.  I want to ask if it's possible to get client ip from user input,using edittext ? Do i need to pass this value here(server), cause before i ran program just in plane java and i didn't do it. Smth like  (if it's the wright place  )

```
server= new ServerSocket("xxx.xxx.x.xxx" ,5555);
```

how can i read value from edittext and use it here?

Comment: the question is not clear. A client is trying to connect you and u want to know the ip-address of the client?

Comment: I want to make on android edittext field to make user input client's ip before connection ( i don't know if it makes sense?) will it affect smth

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but the server can get the IP address of the client from the socket:

```
csocket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
```